# Replace alt text with image in assets file Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my folder structure

```
-- assets
      |
   - missing.jpg
```

and this is the function I used to render the movie div

```
function showMovies(movies) {
  main.innerHTML = "";

  movies.forEach((movie) => {
    const { title, poster_path, vote_average, overview } = movie;

    const movieEl = document.createElement("div");

    movieEl.classList.add("movie");

    movieEl.innerHTML = `
    <img
          src="${IMG_PATH + poster_path}"
          alt="${title}"
        />

        <div class="movie-info">
          <h3>${title}</h3>
          <span class="${getClassByRate(vote_average)}">${vote_average}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="overview">
          <h3>Overview</h3>
              ${overview}
        </div>
    `;
    main.appendChild(movieEl);
  });
}
```

I am trying to change the alt image in this function to display an image in my assets folder instead of just the text title.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain more detailed what you mean. For example what is an "*alt image*"?

Comment: Hi AndresG great to have you as a part of this community, in future question please explain what you are trying to achieve first and try to explain a bit your code and why it is failing, this way is less likely to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to add an image when there is no image found right?

ok, so there are multiple approaches to this problem, first, if you have an invalid path, use the terniary operator to src your image correctly

```js
 src=`${IMG_PATH ? IMG_PATH + poster_path : '/assets/missing.jpg'}`
```

But... if the image fails to load because of the server being unavailable or some 400/500 error then that's a different story, My personal approach is to make a div with the size of the image and set multiple backgrounds using css properties for instance....

```css
background: url("/path_to_movie_poster.gif"), url("/assets/missing.jpg");
```

This way if the first source failed for some reason then the default image will kick in.
Make sure your default image is the last in the least otherwise it will be on top.